# Matching dataframes with multiple matches

Tags: r

I want to match two dataframes using `match`. This works fine for unique matches,as explained in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69203864/merge-two-dataframes-by-different-columns-with-a-loop). The problem is that, sometimes, the value of the first dataframe column matches several rows in the second dataframe. In these cases, I get just the first match but I would like all the matches. In the example in the other answer, suppose that London is both nested in the UK and England and I want to preserve this information. Do you know any possible solution?

This is how my dataframes look like

```
  document keyword1 keyword2
1        1    Paris  London 
2        2 Valencia  Glasgow


  document     area
1    Paris   France
2   London       UK
3   London  England
4 Valencia    Spain
5  Glasgow       UK
6  Glasgow Scotland
```

And this is my desired output

```
  document keyword1 keyword2  area1 area2    area3
1        1    Paris  London  France    UK  England
2        2 Valencia  Glasgow  Spain    UK Scotland
```

My MWE

```
df1 <- structure(list(document = c("1", "2"), keyword1 = c("Paris", "Valencia"), 
                         keyword2 = c("London", "Glasgow")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 <- structure(list(City = c("Paris", "London", "London", "Valencia", "Glasgow", "Glasgow"), 
                      area = c("France", "UK", "England", "Spain", "UK", "Scotland")), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Please look up `merge` or `full_join` in `{dplyr}`.

Comment: Please provide an example. In the absence of this, you could check the option `allow.cartesian=True` of the `merge` command.

Comment: I edited the question with an example, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using the `data.table` package. The key concepts here are: 1. Use `toString` to aggregate multiple strings in `df2`. 2. Merge `df1` and `df2_s` for each keyword, and use `cSplit` from the `splitstackshape` package to split the aggregated strings into different columns.

```
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)

# Convert the data frame to data.table
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

# Use toString to aggregate multiple strings
df2_s <- df2[, .(area = toString(area)), by = City]

# Identify the keyword columns
key_col <- grep("keyword", names(df1), value = TRUE)

df_temp <- data.table::copy(df1)

# A for loop to conduct merge and cSplit for each keyword
for (i in 1:length(key_col)){
  
  df_temp <- merge(df_temp, df2_s, by.x = key_col[i], by.y = "City", all.x = TRUE)
  
  df_temp_name <- names(df_temp)
  
  # Give a new name to the newly merged area column
  df_temp_name[[ncol(df_temp)]] <- paste0("area_", key_col[i])
  
  df_temp <- setNames(df_temp, df_temp_name)
  
  # Split the multiple strings in the area column
  df_temp <- cSplit(df_temp, splitCols = paste0("area_", key_col[i]), type.convert = FALSE)
  
}

new_cols <- c(names(df1), grep("^area_", names(df_temp), value = TRUE))

new_cols2 <- c(names(df1), paste0("area_", 1:(ncol(df_temp) -  ncol(df1))))

# Reorganize the column order
df_final <- df_temp[, ..new_cols]

# Rename the columns
df_final <- setNames(df_final, new_cols2)

df_final <- df_final[order(document)]

df_final
#    document keyword1 keyword2 area_1 area_2   area_3
# 1:        1    Paris   London France     UK  England
# 2:        2 Valencia  Glasgow  Spain     UK Scotland
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
    # Put keyword data into long format
    pivot_longer(
        cols = starts_with("keyword"),
        names_to = "keyword_id",
        values_to = "keyword_value", 
    ) %>%
    # Join with area data
    left_join(
        df2,
        by = c("keyword_value" = "City")
    ) %>%
    # Put area data into long format
    pivot_longer(
        cols = "area",
        names_to = "area_id",
        values_to = "area_value"
    ) %>%
    # Assign area match IDs by document
    group_by(
        document
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        area_id = paste0(area_id, row_number())
    ) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    # Put area data into wide format, dropping keywords 
    pivot_wider(names_from = "area_id", values_from = "area_value", id_cols = "document") %>%
    # Join back with keyword data
    left_join(
        df1,
        by = "document"
    ) %>%
    # Order columns
    select(
        document, starts_with("keyword"), starts_with("area")
    )
```

**Result:**

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 6
  document keyword1 keyword2 area1  area2 area3   
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>  <chr> <chr>   
1 1        Paris    London   France UK    England 
2 2        Valencia Glasgow  Spain  UK    Scotland
```